# Real NVP with tensorflow probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to train a Real NVP with tensorflow probability. However I get a `TypeError` with the following description:

```
The following are legacy tf.layers.Layers:
 <tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f0888763580>
  <tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f0888744b20>
  <tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f0888761df0>
  <tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f088866df40>
  <tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f088866d9a0>
  <tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f0888572220>
To use keras as a framework (for instance using the Network, Model, or Sequential classes), please use the tf.keras.layers implementation instead. (Or, if writing custom layers, subclass from tf.keras.layers rather than tf.layers)
```

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as k
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

realnvp1 = tfp.bijectors.RealNVP(fraction_masked=0.5,
    shift_and_log_scale_fn=tfp.bijectors.real_nvp_default_template(
        hidden_layers=[32,32])
    )

base_distribution = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=[0.,0.])
trainable_distribution = realnvp1(base_distribution)

net_in = k.layers.Input(shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32)
net_out = trainable_distribution.log_prob(net_in)
model = k.Model(net_in,net_out)
```

The last line causes the error. What is the right implementation?

Below I attach the full traceback:

```
2021-07-11 15:52:52.896472: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-07-11 15:52:53.743731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-07-11 15:52:53.766232: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-07-11 15:52:53.766414: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2070 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.83GHz coreCount: 36 deviceMemorySize: 7.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-07-11 15:52:53.766428: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-07-11 15:52:53.769011: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-07-11 15:52:53.769037: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-07-11 15:52:53.769636: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-07-11 15:52:53.769787: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-07-11 15:52:53.770123: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.11
2021-07-11 15:52:53.770679: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2021-07-11 15:52:53.770767: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-07-11 15:52:53.770816: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-07-11 15:52:53.771010: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-07-11 15:52:53.771166: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-07-11 15:52:53.771355: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-07-11 15:52:53.771762: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-07-11 15:52:53.771931: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2070 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.83GHz coreCount: 36 deviceMemorySize: 7.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-07-11 15:52:53.771967: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-07-11 15:52:53.772140: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-07-11 15:52:53.772296: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-07-11 15:52:53.772320: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-07-11 15:52:54.097441: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-07-11 15:52:54.097462: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0 
2021-07-11 15:52:54.097467: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N 
2021-07-11 15:52:54.097580: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-07-11 15:52:54.097755: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-07-11 15:52:54.097936: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-07-11 15:52:54.098093: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 381 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
/home/john/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/legacy_tf_layers/core.py:171: UserWarning: `tf.layers.dense` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `tf.keras.layers.Dense` instead.
  warnings.warn('`tf.layers.dense` is deprecated and '
/home/john/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:2183: UserWarning: `layer.apply` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `layer.__call__` method instead.
  warnings.warn('`layer.apply` is deprecated and '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-147123f84263>", line 16, in <module>
    model = k.Model(net_in,net_out)
  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 522, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 115, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 522, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 227, in _init_graph_network
    tf_utils.assert_no_legacy_layers(self.layers)
  File "/home/john/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py", line 411, in assert_no_legacy_layers
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The following are legacy tf.layers.Layers:
  <tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers.core.Dense object at 0x7ff8602fb640>
  <tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers.core.Dense object at 0x7ff8602fb6a0>
  <tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers.core.Dense object at 0x7ff8602e1850>
  <tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers.core.Dense object at 0x7ff860232310>
  <tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers.core.Dense object at 0x7ff860229fa0>
  <tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers.core.Dense object at 0x7ff860232c10>
To use keras as a framework (for instance using the Network, Model, or Sequential classes), please use the tf.keras.layers implementation instead. (Or, if writing custom layers, subclass from tf.keras.layers rather than tf.layers)
```

Comment: Are you sure these are error messages? They look like warnings, not errors

Comment: Yes, it raises a TypeError

Comment: You need to add all that information in full to your question.

Comment: Just added it for completeness

Comment: No, that is not information in full, add the complete traceback, people can't help you with partial information

Comment: Sorry, now you should find the complete traceback